# Добавить в избранное

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Как организован подсчет пользователей (как на этом сайте), которые добавили вопрос в избранное ?

Меня интересует логика.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Логика простая и абсолютно стандартная, такая же, как для любых других связанных данных: обычная таблица, в которой всего два поля - ид вопроса и ид пользователя.

Соответственно, подсчет делается простейшим SQL запросом.

Comment: Судя по расставленным тегам, товарищ вообще ничего не представляет, начиная с того, как звезда проставляется и кончая тем, как она отрисовывается.